# Updating field from table used as source in network dataset

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase, network-analyst, versioning

I have a Feature Dataset that contains a Network Dataset and a Feature Class (as a source of Network Dataset) in enterprise geodatabase (PostgreSQL). The Feature Dataset is versioned because we want to edit/update and build the network dataset.

In that feature class, I have a field called condition that will be updated if a road segment damaged or in good condition. I set a restriction in the network dataset if the value is damage, the route should not passing that road segment. I planned that value will updated by a system that querying right to the Default version through a versioned view.

Until now, I successfully updated the default version. I checked in arcmap and see the changes of the data. But, the network dataset that I build is not changes. The route still passing through the damaged road.

How should I update a versioned data for a network dataset through SQL?

Comment: Does the same problem occur if the data is NOT versioned?  Ie, verified that versioning is the cause of this issue?

Comment: Have you tried prototyping this workflow without versioning using a file geodatabase first?

Comment: @SonofaBeach No, I facing the same problem when the data not versioned.

Comment: OK, that’s useful information.  It may be worth editing your post to exclude the versioning information if you are 100% sure that versioning is not involved.  Otherwise it just distracts from the essence of the problem.

Comment: @PolyGeo I haven't trying the file geodatabase, because I'm supporting team that develop an apps that not familiar with arcgis environtment

Comment: @SonofaBeach Oh that versioned things still mentioned because I need another option to modifying the data. If I put the data to sde, the requirement to edit the data must be versioned, right?

Comment: SDE Data doesn’t need to be versioned to be edited.  There are other ways.